# SQL*Loader is not loading all records from a CSV file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I'm loading a CSV file through SQL*Loader. It is inserting only 200,000 records from a CSV file which contains around 500,000 records. No bad file is generated and no errors are shown in the log file.

My control file looks like this:

```
Load data
append 
insert into table tablename
Fields terminated by ','
```

and calling `sqlldr` through a Java program:

```
sqlldrcmd username/password@database ctl= ctlfile data = datafile rows =30000 bindsize = 1045789 errors =10000
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What is `sqlldrcmd`? What happens if you run `sqlldr` directly from the command line? And are you sure you're picking up the file you think you are; and discard/log are going where expect?

Comment: What operating system is Windows or Linux in which you are trying to run the program sqlldr?

Comment: windows server 2008

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry sqlldrcmd is just a string calling sqlldr fucntionality from spring application. If I am running sqlldr directly in cmd line it is working but through spring application it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the control file, specify the file from which you get the input:

```
Load data
infile *
append 
insert into table tablename
Fields terminated by ','
```

Also, make sure you specify both the .bad and the .dsc files.